# Input file is not a valid type library

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to reference a dll in my Visual Studio project and I am getting this error:

> Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

I tried using CMD with TlbImp.exe, and I got an error that says "the dll is not valid type library". The dll is written in C++ and I am trying to reference it in C# project.

Comment: do a google search on how to reference a C++ DLL in C# have you tried that

Comment: It depends on how old the dll is.  Some dll to work in a c++ wrapper.  Had same issue last year.  Vendor supplied two dll's  One old one and one wrapper.  To get to work had to manually put both into the exe debug/release folder.  What made the problem worse was there was a different pair of dlls for x32 Windows and x64 windows.

Comment: You're asking us to explain why some unknown DLL does not work in some code we cannot see, which is not going to work. If you want help with an issue with your code, then  a) we need the *minimal* code necessary to demonstrate the problem, and b) we need information about the DLL you're trying to use. You're *assuming* that the C++ DLL  Implements a COM interface, which is not necessarily true, and you're giving us absolutely no information we can use. Contact the author of the DLL and ask them for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the following in a .NET project:

- Another .NET assembly of the same framework version, or prior (.exe or .dll)
- COM components (.exe or .dll).  .NET will have to create a COM wrapper.

For a plain vanilla C linked library (.dll), you have to use the `DllImport` attribute to declare external functions contained in the file, [demonstrated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern).